# Using EF Core Power Tool for an Oracle Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget-package

I am using VS 2022 and trying to use EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer an Oracle database.  I right-click and choose 'Reverse Engineer' and then add a custom connection string (since the other way has been deprecated for Oracle). I enter the connection string for the Oracle database:

"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=)));User Id=;Password=;"

After a few seconds, an empty dialog appears.

[image]

I am not sure what's wrong.  I am not aware if there are any logs I can look at to see what is wrong.

Any suggestions?  Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you need to enter more values in your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late but if you still have the problem then try to install the "Oracle Developer Tools" extensions for Visual Studio and also the Oracle .NET managed driver. And instead of using "Add custom connection" use "Add database connection".

- [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2019)
- [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2022)

Hope it helps.